# Browse and select document library files through a Modal Dialog

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, search, modal-dialog

I have a page which should link documents from a document library as hyperlinks in the page, so that a user can click on the hyperlink and view it. For this purpose,I need to add functionality to add documents from the Document library.

So, I need to select a document in the Document library through a window(maybe a modal popup), and set the selected document's path as a hyperlink. How would be the best way to achieve this?

The functionalities required are

1) Need to browse the document library,

2) **search** for a document and when it's selected by user ... include/capture it's path as a hyperlink.